# Repeated search replace until convergence

Tags: algorithm, replace, convergence

I'm searching for the name and an efficient solution for the following problem: Assume I have a string `s='abcdef'` and a set of find/replace rules `Pn`

```
P1: ab -> xy
P2: xyc -> 123
P3: ef -> ab
```

Sequentially applying these rules to `s` I could arrive at the following strings:

```
1. xycdef
2. 123def
3. 123dab
4. 123dxy
```

My goal is to reach a "stable" state where all (most?) rules have been applied (here: `123dxy`).

So my question is, is there a well defined approach for dealing with this type of problems? Are there general constraints on the rules to avoid infinite loops (eg, `ab -> xy`, `xy -> ab`). Is there a way to determine a bound for the maximum number of iterations?

Any pointers to relevant concepts/related work are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would translate this into a graph problem.
In your case, I would have a node named `ab`, another `xy`, `xyc`, etc.
Directed edges exist between node according to the rules.
Here: `V={ab, xy, xyc, 123, ef}; E={(ab,xy), (xyz.123), (ef, ab)}`

**Basic check:**
If at this stage you have loops in your graph, then you have a real problem.

**Prefixes:**
The case with `ab -> xy` and `xyc -> 123` gives us an issue where two rules are not a problem unless the given string is built in a certain way. (`abc` becomes `xyc`). This could be checked with directed edges that are marked in a certain way. If *they* create a loop, then you will have an issue with certain strings, but not with others.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I was hoping that someone had stumbled upon - and solved - the exact problem already. It doesn't look like it, so I'll accept your answer and start coding.